# I encountered a problem with Go for loop and WaitGroup

Tags: go

I am a newbie who is learning Go and I encountered a problem as follows:

```
type Foo struct {
    Name   string
    Result int
}

func main() {
    foos := make([]Foo, 0)
    foos = append(foos, Foo{"a", 0})
    foos = append(foos, Foo{"bb", 0})
    foos = append(foos, Foo{"ccc", 0})

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for _, f := range foos {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(f *Foo, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
            f.Result = len(f.Name)
            wg.Done()
        }(&f, &wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Println(foos)
}
```

I expected output to be `[{a 1} {bb 2} {ccc 3}]` but the real output is `[{a 0} {bb 0} {ccc 0}]`.

I don't know why. I would appreciate it if anyone can answer my confusion.

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines

Answer (score 2):

When you range foos, the value `f` is a copy of `foos` element. So changing the copy's `Result` has nothing to do with the element in foos. 
To get the result you expected, you can try the following code, using pointers instead.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type Foo struct {
    Name   string
    Result int
}

func main() {
    foos := make([]*Foo, 0)
    foos = append(foos, &Foo{"a", 0})
    foos = append(foos, &Foo{"bb", 0})
    foos = append(foos, &Foo{"ccc", 0})

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for _, f := range foos {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(f *Foo, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
            f.Result = len(f.Name)
            wg.Done()
        }(f, &wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()

    for _, f := range foos {
        fmt.Println(*f)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The `f` is a **local** variable inside the `for` loop, so it is just a **local copy** of the element's **value**, which changes on each loop's iteration, try [this](https://play.golang.org/p/bFlDv2jTFnw) to see the address (is constant), and the value of `f` on every loop iterations:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    foos := []Foo{{"a", 0}, {"bb", 0}, {"ccc", 0}}
    for _, f := range foos {
        fmt.Printf("%p %v\n", &f, f)
    }
}

type Foo struct {
    Name   string
    Result int
}
```

Output:

```
0xc00010c000 {a 0}
0xc00010c000 {bb 0}
0xc00010c000 {ccc 0}
```

2. It is simple and **clean** to write:

```
foos := []Foo{{"a", 0}, {"bb", 0}, {"ccc", 0}}
```

instead of:

```
    foos := make([]Foo, 0)
    foos = append(foos, Foo{"a", 0})
    foos = append(foos, Foo{"bb", 0})
    foos = append(foos, Foo{"ccc", 0})
```

3. Since you are using a **closure**, you don't need to pass a `WaitGroup` refrence too, an index of slice is more **clean** and sufficient:

```
wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
for i := range foos {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(i int) {
        foos[i].Result = len(foos[i].Name)
        wg.Done()
    }(i)
}
```

Try [it](https://play.golang.org/p/i4iWTY986Og) all:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    foos := []Foo{{"a", 0}, {"bb", 0}, {"ccc", 0}}
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    for i := range foos {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(i int) {
            foos[i].Result = len(foos[i].Name)
            wg.Done()
        }(i)
    }
    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Println(foos)
}

type Foo struct {
    Name   string
    Result int
}
```

Output:

```
[{a 1} {bb 2} {ccc 3}]
```